# No registration for type ICommandHandler using SimpleInjector APIv3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, cqrs, simple-injector

I've been playing around with SimpleInjector and I'm trying to register properly all command handlers.

Here is my code:

### CQRS.cs

```
public interface ICommand {}

public interface ICommandDispatcher
{
    void Execute(ICommand command);
}

public class CommandDispatcher : ICommandDispatcher
{
    private readonly Container container;

    public CommandDispatcher(Container container)
    {
        this.container = container;
    }

    public void Execute(ICommand command)
    {
        var handlerType = typeof(ICommandHandler<>).MakeGenericType(command.GetType());

        dynamic handler = container.GetInstance(handlerType);

        handler.Handle((dynamic)command);
    }
}

public interface ICommandHandler<in TParameter> where TParameter : ICommand
{
    void Handle(TParameter command);
}
```

### Handler.cs

```
public class UserCommandsHandler : ICommandHandler<CreateUser>
{
    public void Handle(CreateUser message)
    {
        var user = new User(message.Email);
        /* logic here */
    }
}
```

### Command.cs

```
public class CreateUser : ICommand
{
    public readonly string Email;

    public CreateUser(string email)
    {
        Email = email;
    }       
}
```

### Global.asax.cs

```
var assemblies = new[] { typeof(ICommandHandler<>).Assembly };
var container = new SimpleInjector.Container();
container.RegisterCollection(typeof(ICommandHandler<>), assemblies);
container.RegisterSingleton<ICommandDispatcher>(new CommandDispatcher(container));
container.Verify();
DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new SimpleInjectorDependencyResolver(container));
```

### HomeController.cs

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly ICommandDispatcher _commandDispatcher;

    public HomeController(ICommandDispatcher commandDispatcher)
    {
        _commandDispatcher = commandDispatcher;
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var command = new CreateUser("email@example.com");
        _commandDispatcher.Execute(command);
        return Content("It works");
    }
}
```

at CQRS.cs

```
dynamic handler = container.GetInstance(handlerType);
```

I get:

> No registration for type `ICommandHandler<CreateUser>` could be found. 
>       There is, however, a registration for `IEnumerable<ICommandHandler<CreateUser>>`;
>       Did you mean to call `GetAllInstances<ICommandHandler<CreateUser>>()` or depend on `IEnumerable<ICommandHandler<CreateUser>>`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Simple Injector API clearly [separates between registrations for collections](https://simpleinjector.org/separate-collections) and one-to-one mappings. In your composition root, you are making the following registration:

```
container.RegisterCollection(typeof(ICommandHandler<>), 
    new[] { typeof(ICommandHandler<>).Assembly });
```

The API Documentation for `RegisterCollection` states:

> Registers a collection of serviceTypes, whose instances will be resolved lazily each time the resolved collection of serviceType is enumerated. The underlying collection is a stream that will return individual instances based on their specific registered lifestyle, for each call to `IEnumerator<T>.Current`. The order in which the types appear in the collection is the exact same order that the items were registered, i.e the resolved collection is deterministic.

In other words, you are allowing command handlers to be resolved as collections, by requesting `IEnumerable<ICommandHandler<T>>`.

In your `CommandDispatcher` however, you request a single `ICommandHandler<T>` by calling `container.GetInstance(handlerType)`. Since there is no one-to-one mapping for an `ICommandHandler<T>`, Simple Injector informs you about this by throwing:

> No registration for type `ICommandHandler<CreateUser>` could be found. 
>   There is, however, a registration for `IEnumerable<ICommandHandler<CreateUser>>`;
>   Did you mean to call `GetAllInstances<ICommandHandler<CreateUser>>()` or depend on `IEnumerable<ICommandHandler<CreateUser>>`?

To fix this, there are two options:

1. Either you register your handlers using the one-to-one mapping, or
2. You resolve a collection of handlers within your `CommandDispatcher` by calling `GetAllInstances(Type)`.

Since there will always be a one-to-one mapping between a command and its handler (meaning: there will be exactly one handler per command), option 1 is the most obvious solution. So change your registration to the following:

```
// Use 'Register' instead of 'RegisterCollection'.
container.Register(typeof(ICommandHandler<>), 
    new[] { typeof(ICommandHandler<>).Assembly });
```

Comment: Changed as suggested: I get:
No registration for type ICommandHandler<CreateUser> could be found.

Comment: @R2D2: Make sure that the assembly that contains the command handlers is supplied to the `Register` method and that your command handler implements `ICommandHandler<T>` (and make sure you didn't accidentally define a second `ICommandHandler<T>` abstraction). If that doesn't work, please post your updated configuration (by appending it to your question). What you're doing is very normal, and many Simple Injector users (including myself) do this daily, so it must be something silly.

Comment: You were right. It was something really stupid. All my handlers are in a different assembly than ICommandHandler.

Comment: @R2D2: By the way,  I would advice against using a `CommandDispatcher` at all, but instead inject a `ICommandHandler<T>` directly into your controllers. This makes is much easier to get a [verifiable configuration](https://simpleinjector.readthedocs.org/en/latest/howto.html#verify-configuration). If you see controllers get many command handlers injected, it's an indication that your controllers do too much, violate the Single Responsibility Principle.